# Dynamic arguments without elipses in Typescript

Tags: typescript

```
  // Function definition:
  lm( vv: number, kk: string[] )
  {
    console.log( kk )
  }

  // Calling
  this.lm( 33, ["dd","ff","da"] )
```

I have tested the above code. It works fine.

**Why do we require elipses then?**

From: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

```
function buildName(firstName: string, ...restOfName: string[]) {
    return firstName + " " + restOfName.join(" ");
}
```

> The compiler will build an array of the arguments passed in with the name given after the ellipsis (...), allowing you to use it in your function.

Comment: I think both are the same, but rest is optional and to make your example exactly the same you should provide default value equal to an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are comparing two different thing. The both following examples will end up in the same display but are not called in the same way.

In fact theses are two different concepts (syntax) ; that both have different uses cases.

```
  // Function definition:
  lm( vv: number, kk: string[] )
  {
    console.log( kk )
  }

  // Calling
  this.lm( 33, ["dd","ff","da"] )
```

and

```
  // Function definition:
  lm( vv: number, ...kk: string[] )
  {
    console.log( kk )
  }

  // Calling
  this.lm( 33, "dd","ff","da" )
```

---

An example where ellipsis is better use :

```
type funcDefinition = (commandName: number, ...params: string[]) => void;

const funcA: funcDefinition = (vv: number, p1: string = 'defA', p2: string = 'defB', ...othersParams: string[]) => {
  console.log(vv, p1, p2, othersParams);
}

const funcB: funcDefinition = (vv: number, p1: string, ...othersParams: string[]) => {
  console.log(vv, p1, othersParams);
}

const funcC: funcDefinition = (vv: number, ...othersParams: string[]) => {
  console.log(vv, othersParams);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please point out a great documentation for Typescript?

Comment: For documentation I google `typescript [SUBJECT]` then I browse articles. [medium.com](https://medium.com/) holds a good amount of articles. I don't have a specific url for you, sorry.